# Question Pattern/Matcher

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I want to extract the value 5342test behind the name="buddyname" from a fieldset tag.
But there are multiple fieldsets in the HTML code.
Below the example of the string in the HTML.

```
<fieldset style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="buddyname" value="5342test" /></fieldset>
```

I have some difficulties to put in the different patterns in Pattern.compile and i just want the value 5342test displayed not the other results, could somebody please help?
Thank you.

My code:

```
String stringToSearch = "5342test";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\value=\\})");  
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(stringToSearch);

            while (m.find())
            {
              // get the matching group
              String codeGroup = m.group(1);

              // print the group
              System.out.format("'%s'\n", codeGroup); // should be 5342test
            }
```

Comment: [Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/600500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<input[^>]*?value\\s*?=\\s*?\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
```

Comment: Hi Andrei,First of all thank you but i get an error in eclipse in this section (.*?)\\")" of your example.

Comment: It says Syntac errors on tokens, delete these tokens.
Thx for reviewing.

Comment: I did not exactly put in your example, my mistake ;) but still got an error. LogCat: 09-25 13:53:49.090: WARN/System.err(3120): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN near index 36:
09-25 13:57:35.091: WARN/System.err(3341): <input[^>]*?value\s*?=\s*?\"(.*?)\")

Comment: Oops, my bad. Remove extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: To match a quotation mark (`"`) all you need is `\"`, not `\\\"`.  It only needs to be escaped because it's in a string literal; it has no special meaning for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the input values inside a fieldset tag, you can use this regex pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<fieldset[^>]*>[^<]*<input.+?value\\s*=\\s*\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<fieldset style=\"display:none\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"buddyname\" value=\"5342test\" /></fieldset>");
if (matcher.find()) 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //this prints 5342test
else
    System.out.println("Input html does not have a fieldset");
```

Comment: As Paŭlo Ebermann said, it is better to avoid using regex to parse HTML because HTML is not a regular language.